# Wireshark filtering for ip-port pair(Display filter)

Tags: wireshark

I'd like to know how to make a display filter for ip-port in wireshark.

So, for example I want to filter ip-port 10.0.0.1:80, so it will find all the communication to and from 10.0.0.1:80, but not communication from 10.0.0.1:235 to some ip on port 80.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I want to filter out ip-port pair for any protocol that suports ports. Either tcp or udp. That ip-por pair can contact any other ip on any port.

`(ip.src == XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX && (tcp.srcport == YYY || udp.srcport == YYY)) || (ip.dst == XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX && (tcp.dstport == YYY || udp.dstport == YYY)` will match:

- all packets coming from IPv4 address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX and TCP or UDP port YYY;
- all packets going to IPv4 address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX and TCP or UDP port YYY;

which sounds as if it's what you want.  (If it's not what you want, you'll have to be even more specific and precise about what you want.)

Comment: FYI there seems to be a `)` missing at the end for anyone using this

Answer (score 1):

The IP protocol doesn't define something like a port. Two protocols on top of IP have ports TCP and UDP.

If you want to display only packets of a TCP connection sent from port 80 of one side and to port 80 of the other side you can use this display filter:

```
tcp.srcport==80 && tcp.dstport==80
```

Similar you can define a filter for a UDP communication. You can narrow the filter with addtional conditions like

```
ip.srcaddr==1.2.3.4
```

or

```
ip.addr==55.66.77.88
```

You can even use the C style operators && and || as well as parentheses to build complex filters.

```
(ip.addr==128.100.1.1 && tcp.port==80) || (ip.addr==10.1.2.1 && udp.port==68)
```

What you actually want to filter is your decision.

Comment: That's not what I want. I want to filter out ip-port pair for any protocol that suports ports. Either tcp or udp. That ip-por pair can contact any other ip on any port.

Comment: May I ask why did you use parenthesis around `&&`? Is it like "single bracket" `test` (`[]`) in Bash? If so, please share a reference that explains it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this filter:

```
(ip.src==10.0.0.1 and tcp.srcport==80) or (ip.dst==10.0.0.1 and tcp.dstport==80)
```

Since you've got two ports and two IPs in tcp/ip packets you need to specify exactly what source and destination sockets you want.

Comment: If you want to filter for identical `srcport` or `dstport` you can simplify the filter and use just `port`. Your example would be "ip.src==10.0.0.1 and tcp.port==80"